# Cannot validate a contained resource with Simplifier.net

Tags: hl7-fhir

We are testing against SIMPLIFIER.NET the FHIR resource shown below.

It is an Encounter containing a Task. As encounters cannot reference tasks directly, we are using reverse references.

According to the standard R4, "For a resource that references the container, the reference is '#'."

Problem is that Simplifier throws exceptions in that case, while Confluence and Gazelle don't:

[image]

The question is: Is that FHIR resource well formed?

```json
{

    "resourceType": "Encounter",

    "status": "planned",

    "contained": [{

        "resourceType": "Task",

        "status": "requested",

        "intent": "order",

        "note": [{

            "text": "Task 2"

        }],

        "id": "task1",

"encounter": { "reference": "#" }

    }],

    "class": {

        "display": "Pre Op"

    },

    "subject": {

        "reference": "Patient/83479"

    },

    "episodeOfCare": [{

        "reference": "EpisodeOfCare/FC93408C-6E0E-4003-B984-A6B4CE7334B8"

    }],

    "basedOn": [{

        "reference": "ServiceRequest/332276C4-12FA-4576-AE1D-6865C267BDD5"

    }],

    "participant": [{

        "individual": {

            "reference": "Practitioner/cea0b20a-e162-4065-a16d-766697e647ac"

        }

    }],

    "meta": {

        "lastUpdated": "2021-10-06T10:09:40.070-05:00"

    },

    "id": "B3E42476-A8FE-4848-9F2B-F3F9126E88C6"

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[The FHIRPath definition of the `ref-1` invariant](http://www.hl7.org/fhir/references.html) currently does not allow for referencing the container resource from the contained resource, only for referencing other contained resources:

```
reference.startsWith('#').not() or (reference.substring(1).trace('url') in %rootResource.contained.id.trace('ids'))
```

A [ticket for changing this in the FHIR specification](https://jira.hl7.org/browse/FHIR-31732) has already been filed and approved for changing this, but it has not yet been applied.